# Why (const char * ) argument in fopen prototype in C header stdio.h

Tags: c, header

I don't truly understand it. I am just a student and I notice something in stdio.h

```
extern FILE *fopen (const char *__restrict __filename,
                 const char *__restrict __modes)
```

why we pass "const char * " ???, if I know this mean pass the pointer to char type constant variable. But __filename like "hello.txt" is strings type, not char type. Or the one we pass here is address of this filename, but is that address is char type????

-- I also confused, is this * belong to __restrict or __filename, is this __restrict is the same as keyword restrict we use when declare normal C function in C99.

--Why in other function prototype like

```
extern int fseek (FILE *__stream, long int __off, int __whence);
```

pass "long int __off" not pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Passing a String

> why we pass "const char * " ???, if I know this mean pass the pointer to char type constant variable. But __filename like "hello.txt" is strings type, not char type.

C does not have a “strings type.” In C, a string is an array of `char` whose end is marked by a null character (a character with value zero). Although in a call such as `fopen("myfile", "r")`, we use `"myfile"` as an argument, the array `"myfile"` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Its first element is a `char`, so this pointer is a `char *`.

This comes from a rule in the C standard, in C 2018 6.3.2.1 3, which says that any expression with type “array of *type*” is converted to a pointer to its first element, except when:

- the expression is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`, or
- is a string literal used to initialize an array (as in `char x[] = "abc";`).

### `const` in a parameter

The fact that the parameter has type `const char *` does not mean we have to pass a pointer to something that is `const`. We can pass a plain pointer to a `char`, a `char *`, and it will be automatically converted to a `const char *`. This indicates the function will treat the characters as `const`. In other words, the function will only read the characters; it will not modify them.

(Technically, a pointer of type `const char *` can be legally converted to `char *` and used to modify the objects that are pointed to, as long as those objects were not originally defined with `const`. But this is something used for special circumstances. Normal function definitions that use `const` in their parameters do not do this.)

### `__restrict` in a parameter

> -- I also confused, is this * belong to __restrict or __filename, is this __restrict is the same as keyword restrict we use when declare normal C function in C99.

`__restrict` is used inside some C headers to mean either nothing (when compiling for old versions of C) or `restrict` (when compiling for modern versions of C). For example, in the headers Apple distributes with its developer tools, `<stdio.h>` includes a header which defines `__restrict` this way:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901
#define __restrict
#else
#define __restrict      restrict
#endif
```

The compiler defines (or omits defining) `__STDC_VERSION__` according to the version of C it is compiling for (which can be selected with command-line switches, such as `-std=c17`). Then the statements above define `__restrict` so that `restrict` is not used when compiling for very old versions of C but is used when compiling for modern versions.

### Offset for `fseek`

> Why in other function prototype like ...`fseek`... pass "long int __off" not pointer?

The `off` parameter specifies an offset in a file on disk or other storage. It is not the address of something in main memory, so it is not a pointer. It is a number of bytes from the beginning of the file, so it is a number.

Answer (score -1):

> why we pass "const char * " ???, if I know this mean pass the pointer
>   to char type constant variable. But __filename like "hello.txt" is
>   strings type, not char type. Or the one we pass here is address of
>   this filename, but is that address is char type????

In "C", a string constant (e.g., "hello.txt") is the same as null terminated char array. The address of the string is the position of the first char. For security/reliability, most modern compiler will place those strings into read-only section of the program, and make the type of the constant 'const char **', reducing the change for unexpected program behavior.

Comment: The type of a string literal does not include `const` regardless of whether the C implementation puts it in read-only storage.

Comment: The -Wwrite-string will make gcc produce warning for char *x = "abcd" ; - same as g++. Better safe than sorry.